# The symbolic link /env/.Python targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to push my django site to github. I keep getting that error.

```
The symbolic link /env/.Python targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository
```

The repository is viewable here:

- https://github.com/purplemilk/CLFAKESITE
- https://github.com/purplemilk/purplemilk.github.io

I feel really dumb because I don't exactly know what I'm doing here or if my django site is even actually compatible with github pages.
I'm fairly certain `/env/` is necessary to build the site.
I tried to create a submodule and I also added `.nojekyll`

The commits are all sorts of messed up.
If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong and what I should be doing ELI5 style, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-symlink-does-not-exist-within-your-site-s-repository/):

> If your GitHub Pages site includes a symbolic link (also known as a symlink) to another file or directory that does not exist within your site's repository, your site will not build.
>
> If you do not intend the indicated file to be a symlink, or if you do not use the indicated file to build your site, in many cases, you may safely delete it.

[`purplemilk.github.io`](https://github.com/purplemilk/purplemilk.github.io) includes [`purplemilk/CLFAKESITE`](https://github.com/purplemilk/CLFAKESITE) as a submodule, which in turn has [`purplemilk/CLFAKESITE/env/.Python`](https://github.com/purplemilk/CLFAKESITE/blob/master/env/.Python), a symlink with an absolute path in it.

If you can, remove it,  then push again the second repo, and update your submodule reference in the first repo. For that, go in the `purplemilk.github.io/CLFAKESITE` subfolder, `git pull origin master`, go back to the parent folder, add, commit and push.